# What is going on when you use Array(n).fill(Array(m).fill('_')) and you try to change 1 field, it changes multiple

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example:

```
let arr1 = Array(8).fill(Array(8).fill('_'))

arr1[3][5] = 'N'

console.log(arr) /* [
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
   ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "N", "_", "_"],
] */
```

I changed 1 field, and yet I change 8.

My initial thought was ok, maybe I need to make a new instance of Array, but even if I do the same thing but use `new` like this:

```
let arr2 = new Array(8).fill(new Array(8).fill('_'))

arr2[3][5] = 'N'
```

it does exactly the same.

It completely baffles me, can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: Because you're making an array containing multiple references to the same one array.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but if it's a `new Array` it's not the same array right?

OOOH, I think I get it, first array gets filled with 8 instances of the second new array, d'oh. thanks

Comment: `new Array(8).fill('_').map( i => new Array(8).fill('_') )`

Comment: thanks, I found another workaround:

`[...Array(8)].map(row => new Array(8).fill('_'))`